# Difference between 2 Xpath expressions

Tags: xml, xpath

What's the difference between these two Xpath expressions?

```
$z!="actors"
and
not($z="actors")
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is spelled out in detail in [the XPath specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#booleans):

> **NOTE**: If `$x` is bound to a node-set, then `$x="foo"` does not mean the same as `not($x!="foo")`: the former is true if and only if *some* node in `$x` has the string-value `foo`; the latter is true if and only if *all* nodes in `$x` have the string-value `foo`.

Essentially, all the general comparison operators `=`, `!=`, `<`, `<=`, `>` and `>=` are implicitly existentially quantified over their arguments - `X op Y` is true if there is *any pair* of values from X and Y that satisfies the condition.

```
$z != "actors"
```

means there is a node in `$z` that has a value other than "actors" (and there may also be other nodes in `$z` that *do* have the value "actors", the test will still be true if any of them have a different value), whereas

```
not($z = "actors")
```

means it is *not* the case that there is a node in `$z` whose value *is* "actors".